Contradicting call volume information from LIST /communications/callRecord and GET /reports/getTeamsUserActivityCounts endpoints
We downloaded one day worth of call records using the callrecord LIST endpoint. We used the filter options (strtdatetime) to limit the results.
When we compare the call volume in the return to the call volume shown on Microsoft Dashboards there is a huge difference for the same date. 5K vs 15K calls. Graph API reports 5K (p2p and group), dashboards report 15K (calls).
Please note that the issue persists for all days.
We used a shell script to go through callrecord LIST API and scanned all the returned pages. The returned raw json data was saved in a local folder.
We used grep to scan all the JSON files and counted the number of the word "version". The result was 5K.
